# msbuild fail on win 2008 R2 on CLI/C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, command-line-interface, windows-server-2008-r2

I've just installed VS2012 on my win2008 R2 64 bitserver. Then created simple hello world CLI/C++ projects. When i try to compile this I got the following error:

```
stdafx.cpp : fatal error C1197: cannot reference 'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework
\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll' as the program has already referenced '
c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework
\v4.5\mscorlib.dll' [C:\Users\simbuildop\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Pr
ojects\ConsoleApplication10\ConsoleApplication10\ConsoleApplication10.vcxproj]
```

the call to the C++ compiler created by msbuild is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /AI"C:\Program 
Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramew
ork\v4.5\\" /AI"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\References
\CommonConfiguration   \Neutral" /AI"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Mic
rosoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\\" /Zi /clr /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D 
WIN32 /D _DEBUG /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /EHa /MDd /GS /fp:preci
se /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Yc"stdafx.h" /Fp"Debug\ConsoleApplication10.pch" 
/Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc110.pdb" /TP /FUC:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Fra
mework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll /FU"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference    
Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll" /FUC:\Window
s\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll /FUC:\Windows\Microsoft.NET  
\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll /analyze- /errorReport:queue /
clr:nostdlib stdafx.cpp
stdafx.cpp
```

It is really strange that msbuild is trying to pull .net 2.0 as well as .net 4.5 into the build.

Whats is wrong ?

Regards Michael

Comment: Please paste your code (including StdAfx files) and project settings

Comment: It fails even for a newly created project created "hello World" clr project without any modifications

Comment: You must have somehow messed with project settings. I've created C++ CLR app with Visual 2012 (Srv2008 R2, 64 bits) and it builds just fine. My CL.exe call line does not contain references to .net 2

Answer (score 0):

I am having this same problem trying to upgrade a VS 2005 project all the way to 2015.  I started by upgrading to 2008, and then to 2010 to be able to tap into side-by-side IDE's and round-tripping.  My problem was a little different though as I am trying to target `.Net 2.0` and not `.Net 4.0`.

I had to manually update the `.vcxproj` to use the target framework I wanted using the `Project ToolsVersion`noted below.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="2.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

I also had previously switched the settings to using /CLR which I then switched back to `No Common Language Runtime Support`.  I did a `Rebuild` after tweaking this and the project built with 0 errors.